# PhpStorm: Highlighted Command in Terminal not Readable

Tags: terminal, phpstorm

When entering a command  in the terminal tool window in phpStorm, the command is recognized and highlighted. But since the foreground and background colors are quite the same, I cannot read the command any longer:

[image: The red bar is censorship, gray bar is unreadable]

*The red bar is censorship :-), gray bar is the problem*

Where can I change these settings? I don't need commands to be highlighted.

PhpStorm Version: 2021.1.3

Comment: What version of PhpStrom are you using (*Help | Find Action | About*)?

Comment: Version 2021.1.3, edited question

Comment: It might be [this one](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-269058). Check how it goes in [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/nextversion/)

Comment: @EugeneMorozov: Thanks. I'll wait for the next release.